# How a check an entry condition for every three days?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working on a strategy and it goes like this. Based on the conditions which we will check today, the strategy will decide whether to enter the trade or not for the next three days, and after the completion of three days, the condition will be again checked.

For example, today is 13-07-2022, and based on conditions, we will check whether we will trade or not on 14-07, 15-07, and 16-07. Again will check the condition on 17-07 whether to trade next three days or not.

I had done the basic work and went through the documentation of pine but hardly any luck. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a counter. add 1 at every candle and reset it to zero every three candles. Only check condition when counter is zero

```
var counter = 0

if counter == 0
   check_condition()

counter = counter + 1

if counter == 3
   counter := 0
```

The is extremely simplified, i don't know what's your condition.